# can I avoid these nested for loops?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I have a data frame with a response variable, Y, and three factors, 'factor.a', 'factor.b', and 'factor.c'

I am trying to write a function that will

1. remove a columns from a data frame if all levels of the factor are the same
2. add the terms 'beta.factor.x[1..n]' to a vector of parameters when there is more than one level of a factor, up to 5 levels.
3. exclude the parameter beta.factor.b[1] from in the list (it is fixed)

Here is my code. I think it looks nice and works well, but I have read that it is best to avoid nested for loops, so I am curious if there is a more efficient approach.

```
data <- data.frame(       y = c(1,2,3,4),
                   factor.a = c(1, 1, 2, 1),
                   factor.b = c(1, 2, 2, 3),
                   factor.c = c(0, 0, 0, 0))

model.parms <- list(factor.a  = length(unique(data$factor.a)),
                    factor.b  = length(unique(data$factor.b)),
                    factor.c  = length(unique(data$factor.c)))
vars <- 'beta.o'
for (x in c('factor.a','factor.c', 'factor.b')) {
  if(model.parms[[x]] == 1) {
    data <- data[, -which(names(data) == x)]
  } else {
    m <- min(model.parms[[x]], 5)
    for (i in 1:m) {
      if(!i == 1 && x == 'factor.b') {
        vars <- c(vars, paste('beta.', x, '[', i, ']', sep=''))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any loops at all

```
vars <- c('beta.o',
  paste('sd.', names(model.parms)[model.parms > 1], sep = ''),
  paste('beta.factor.b', '[', 1 +  seq_len(min(model.parms[["factor.b"]], 5) - 1), ']', sep='')
)
data <- data[, names(model.parms)[model.parms > 1]]
```

Comment: This looks very nice, and certainly points me in the right direction for simplifying my code, but I notice two things: first, 'x' is not defined in your answer (it was in my for loop, and second, the number of vars to be added needs to change for each factor.

Comment: I changed the code. Now it should yield the same result as your code. Allthough I notice that you omited the part with sd. in your orginal code.

Comment: Thanks. I removed sd just to simplify the question. your approach works nicely.

Comment: what about the case where either model.parms[['factor.b']] == 1?

Answer (score 1):

You can often void nested loops with by(). Taking your data frame,

```
> out <- by(data,data[,-1],identity)
> out
```

will get you

```
factor.a: 1
factor.b: 1
factor.c: 0
  y factor.a factor.b factor.c
1 1        1        1        0
------------------------------------------------------------ 
factor.a: 2
factor.b: 1
factor.c: 0
NULL
------------------------------------------------------------ 
factor.a: 1
factor.b: 2
factor.c: 0
  y factor.a factor.b factor.c
2 2        1        2        0
------------------------------------------------------------ 
factor.a: 2
factor.b: 2
factor.c: 0
  y factor.a factor.b factor.c
3 3        2        2        0
------------------------------------------------------------ 
factor.a: 1
factor.b: 3
factor.c: 0
  y factor.a factor.b factor.c
4 4        1        3        0
------------------------------------------------------------ 
factor.a: 2
factor.b: 3
factor.c: 0
NULL
```

if you `unclass(out)`, you will get a matrix or array of mode `list`; each element will contain the rows of the original data frame that is aggregated by the levels specified in the second argument of `by()`. Of course, you can replace the `identity` function with another function that operates on that subset of the data frame (the output will always be a matrix or array, but not necessarily of mode `list`, depending on what you return from your function).